# My postfix and dovecot can't receive mail and can't connect from my MUA

Tags: linux, email, centos, postfix-mta, dovecot

I install postfix and dovecot.
When I send an email from my Gmail to my host then I connect it from my computer's email client I got the blow log.
T try to change "`destinations =`", but this error still exists.

```
Dec 23 04:22:55 mail postfix/smtpd[21018]: connect from mail-it0-f50.google.com[209.85.214.50]
Dec 23 04:22:56 mail postfix/smtpd[21018]: 115283F3C0: client=mail-it0-f50.google.com[209.85.214.50]
Dec 23 04:22:56 mail postfix/cleanup[21028]: 115283F3C0: message-id=<CACRj=7md8ZVR54Y3b4OgmYTtHLd6wAHejexZPY_=+UjSDKui6A@mail.gmail.com>
Dec 23 04:22:56 mail postfix/qmgr[14528]: 115283F3C0: from=<mygmail@gmail.com>, size=2554, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 23 04:22:56 mail postfix/smtpd[21018]: disconnect from mail-it0-f50.google.com[209.85.214.50]
Dec 23 04:22:56 mail postfix/pipe[21031]: 115283F3C0: to=<i@myhost.com>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.15, delays=0.1/0.01/0/0.04, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (user unknown)
Dec 23 04:22:56 mail postfix/cleanup[21028]: 32EF83F5C7: message-id=<20171223042256.32EF83F5C7@mail.myhost.com>
Dec 23 04:22:56 mail postfix/qmgr[14528]: 32EF83F5C7: from=<>, size=4295, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 23 04:22:56 mail postfix/bounce[21034]: 115283F3C0: sender non-delivery notification: 32EF83F5C7
Dec 23 04:22:56 mail postfix/qmgr[14528]: 115283F3C0: removed
Dec 23 04:23:26 mail postfix/smtp[21035]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.206.26]:25: Connection timed out
Dec 23 04:23:26 mail postfix/smtp[21035]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400d:c08::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Dec 23 04:23:26 mail postfix/smtp[21035]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2800:3f0:4003:c00::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Dec 23 04:23:56 mail postfix/smtp[21035]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.186.26]:25: Connection timed out
Dec 23 04:23:56 mail postfix/smtp[21035]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400b:c00::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Dec 23 04:23:56 mail postfix/smtp[21035]: 32EF83F5C7: to=<mygmail@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=60, delays=0/0.01/60/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400b:c00::1b]:25: Network is unreachable)
Dec 23 04:26:16 mail postfix/anvil[21020]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:209.85.214.50) at Dec 23 04:22:55
Dec 23 04:26:16 mail postfix/anvil[21020]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:209.85.214.50) at Dec 23 04:22:55
Dec 23 04:26:16 mail postfix/anvil[21020]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Dec 23 04:22:55
Dec 23 04:26:33 mail postfix/smtpd[21045]: connect from unknown[117.181.50.20]
Dec 23 04:26:43 mail postfix/smtpd[21045]: warning: unknown[117.181.50.20]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed:
Dec 23 04:26:51 mail postfix/smtpd[21045]: warning: unknown[117.181.50.20]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed:
Dec 23 04:27:00 mail postfix/smtpd[21045]: warning: unknown[117.181.50.20]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed:
Dec 23 04:27:08 mail postfix/smtpd[21045]: warning: unknown[117.181.50.20]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed:
Dec 23 04:27:08 mail postfix/smtpd[21045]: disconnect from unknown[117.181.50.20]
Dec 23 04:27:09 mail dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (auth failed, 6 attempts in 40 secs): user=<i>, method=PLAIN, rip=117.181.50.20, lip=45.77.77.104, TLS, session=<yB1OVvpgOAB1tTIU>
```

My main.cf:

```
myhostname = mail.myhost.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
message_size_limit = 30720000
virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /root/key/mail.myhost.com.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /root/key/mail.myhost.com.key
virtual_create_maildirsize = yes
virtual_maildir_extended = yes
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
```

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring servers. ServerFault.com would be a better place for questions like this.

Comment: So you're connecting your email client to read your messages in dovecot imap?  I'm not sure I understand exactly where the problem is.  I see a sasl auth error in the logs.